# Option to hide all series highcharter-R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have a chart using highcharter:

```
library(highcharter)

year <- c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)
black <- c(12, 15, 23, 16, 11)
asian <- c(3, 12, 63, 46, 21)
white <- c(5, 45, 44, 44, 4)
hispanic <- c(23, 25, 44, 16, 112)

df <- data.frame(year, black, asian, white, hispanic)

highchart() %>% 
    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = df$year) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="White",data = df$white) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Black",data = df$black) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Asian",data = df$asian) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Hispanic",data = df$hispanic)
```

If I click one of the series on the legend, it hides it:

[image]

Is there a way to have a button or something that toggles ALL series on and off (i.e. hide all series at the click of a button)? For example, if there's many items in the series, it's too difficult to click each one on and off..

### Update

I've tried the solution suggested below, and while I can get it to work within an rMarkdown document, when I knit to an HTML document, the button fails with the error "task must be a function":

[image]

When I trace the error back, under the "sources" tab when I inspect the HTML page, I see:

```
function evalAndRun(tasks, target, args) {
                    if (tasks) {
                        forEach(tasks, function(task) {
                            var theseArgs = args;
                            if (typeof (task) === "object") {
                                theseArgs = theseArgs.concat([task.data]);
                                task = task.code;
                            }
                            var taskFunc = tryEval(task);
                            if (typeof (taskFunc) !== "function") {
                                throw new Error("Task must be a function! Source:\n" + task);
                            }
                            taskFunc.apply(target, theseArgs);
                        });
                    }
                }
```

So for some reason, it's not recognizing the `toggleSeries` function as a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(highcharter)
library(htmlwidgets)

year <- c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)
black <- c(12, 15, 23, 16, 11)
asian <- c(3, 12, 63, 46, 21)
white <- c(5, 45, 44, 44, 4)
hispanic <- c(23, 25, 44, 16, 112)

df <- data.frame(year, black, asian, white, hispanic)

js_code <- "
function toggleSeries() {
  var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
  var series = chart.series;
  
  if (series[0].visible) {
    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
      series[i].hide();
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
      series[i].show();
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('toggleButton').addEventListener('click', toggleSeries);
"

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$year) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "White", data = df$white) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Black", data = df$black) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Asian", data = df$asian) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Hispanic", data = df$hispanic)

hc <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(hc, tags$button("Toggle All", id = "toggleButton"))

hc <- htmlwidgets::onRender(hc, js_code)

hc
```

Comment: Thank you - this works in an rMarkdown document, but when I knit to an HTML, it fails - any idea why this might be happening?  it doesn't like the JS code..

Comment: @DiamondJoe12  here it worked perfectly in html. Try: hc <- htmlwidgets::onRender(hc, sprintf("function(el) {%s}", js_code))

Comment: dang, so weird.  Your suggestion got rid of the error but the onclick still doesn't work (just does nothing).  Very strange.

Comment: try this notation: js <- JS("function () { .... }")

Comment: @magdalena - where exactly am I putting this code?  Sorry I'm not quite understanding.  I the R script?

Comment: Currently, you use the following notation: js_code <- "
function toggleSeries() {rest of the toggle code}". ; try to use js <- JS("function toggleSeries() { rest of the toggle code}")

Comment: I opened a new question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76740008/toggle-button-working-with-highcharter-in-r-studio-but-not-working-when-rendered