# Toggle button working with highcharter in R Studio but NOT working when rendered in HTML

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-markdown, r-highcharter

I have a chart using Highcharter in RMarkdown.  I have a toggle button which toggles on and off the entire series.  While this works perfectly in RStudio, I'm finding that the button does not work when the RMarkdown is knit to an HTML document:

```
library(highcharter)
library(htmlwidgets)

year <- c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)
black <- c(12, 15, 23, 16, 11)
asian <- c(3, 12, 63, 46, 21)
white <- c(5, 45, 44, 44, 4)
hispanic <- c(23, 25, 44, 16, 112)

df <- data.frame(year, black, asian, white, hispanic)

js_code <- "
function toggleSeries() {
  var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
  var series = chart.series;
  console.log(chart)
  console.log(series)//In RStudio - this is an array of 4, in HTML, it's only 1.
  
  if (series[0].visible) {
    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
      series[i].hide();
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
      series[i].show();
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('toggleButton').addEventListener('click', toggleSeries);
"

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$year) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "White", data = df$white) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Black", data = df$black) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Asian", data = df$asian) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Hispanic", data = df$hispanic)

hc <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(hc, tags$button("Toggle All", id = "toggleButton"))

hc <- htmlwidgets::onRender(hc, sprintf("function(el) {%s}", js_code))

hc
```

After trying to do some troubleshooting, I realized that in RStudio, if I inspect the "chart" and "series" variables, the series is an array of 4.  But, when I inspect the output HTML, the series is only an array of 1.  I'm not sure why this is.

Here's an example:

RStudio (RMarkdown) inspecting the chart (working properly, series is array with multiple objects):

[image]

HTML inspecting the chart (not working properly, series is an array of 1 when it should be multiple):

[image]

I've tried wrapping my JavaScript code using something like this: `js_code <- JS("function toggleSeries() { rest of the toggle code}")` but still no luck.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Could you include some more code, which produces some output (`knit` to `HTML`) where the not working button is directly visible?